# How do I set enable_https_traffic_only using Python SDK in Azure?

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to write a Python script to enable "Secure transfer enabled" on an Azure storage account. I'm having some trouble understanding what I need to put in for the following piece of code:

```
storage_account = storage_client.storage_accounts.update(
    GROUP_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, 
    StorageAccountUpdateParameters(enable_https_traffic_only(bool=true))
)
```

I've tried just about every combination I can think of to set this value to true, has anyone got this scenario to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid Python:

```
storage_account = storage_client.storage_accounts.update(
    GROUP_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, 
    StorageAccountUpdateParameters(enable_https_traffic_only = True)
)
```

This page might help:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-python-manage/blob/master/example.py

Comment: Thanks Laurent - I'd tried lots of different combinations, the code I pasted was just the last one in desperation. Your advice worked - life saver!